# JavaScript Binary search w/out array

Tags: javascript, binary-search

I am trying to create a number guessing game using JavaScript for a code challenge and I am very new to this language and need some help.

The premise of the game is to have the computer guess what the user's number is between 0 and 100. The parameters are to use if-else statements and confirm functions with in a while loop. It has been suggested to use a binary search (without using and array) that will move through the loop; narrowing down the computer's guesses by asking the user if their number is higher, lower, or equal to the computers current guess.

As you can see below, I was able to start the if statement and give a result if the user confirms the statement is true. But now I'm stuck on how to continue with the else if statement, continue the loop, and successfully implement a binary search. I've started the else if statement, but I know this is most likely not the way to go. I have tried to search through stack-overflow and other sites on how to use a binary search, however all results came back with using it through an array which I cannot do. Any help and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```js
var guessNumGame = function () {
 'use strict';
 var low = 0;
 var high = 100;
 var number;

 alert("Think of a number betwwen 0 and 100");
 while (low <= high) {
  number = Math.round((low + high) / 2);

  if (window.confirm("Is your number " + number + " ? Click OK for 
        Yes, CANCEL for No.") == true ) {

    alert("You got it! Thanks for playing!");

  } //this is where I'm stuck on how to proceed and below is unfinished

        else if (window.confirm("Is your number higher or lower? Click OK 
        for higher, CANCEL for lower. ") < true) {

    window.confirm("Is your number " + number / 2 + " ? Click OK 
             for Yes, CANCEL for No.") == true;

  }else {

   return guess;
  }

   return; // this return is here just to avoid and infinite loop
 }

};

window.onload = guessNumGame;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Pick a Number</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Pick a number for me to guess</h1>
    <script src="js/pick_number.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code implements your idea, what you're trying to achieve is very interesting! But the idea of achieving it doesn't seem to be convenient.

```js
var guessNumGame = function () {
 'use strict';
 var low = 0;
 var high = 100;
 var number;

 alert("Think of a number betwwen 0 and 100");
 while (low <= high) {
     number = Math.floor((Math.random() * (high - low + 1))) + low;
  if (window.confirm("Is your number " + number + " ? Click OK for Yes, CANCEL for No."))
    return alert("YAAAY! I WON");
      if (window.confirm("Is your number higher or lower? Click OK for higher, CANCEL for lower. ")) {
   low = number + 1;
  } else {
   high = number - 1;
  }
 }

};

guessNumGame();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use while loops in conjuction with your confirm statements to create this in a simple manner.

Notes:

1. I have wrapped the confirms in a helper function to improve code readability.
2. I skipped the prompt to check if it's lower after asking if it's higher because it is redundant.

Sample

```js
function guessNumber(number) {
  return confirm('Is ' + number + ' your number?');
}

function askIfHigher(number) {
  return confirm('Is your number greater than ' + number + '?');
}

function startGame() {
  // Initialise variables
  var low = 0,
    high = 100,
    mid,
    complete = false;

  // Repeat while we have not guessed the answer or binary search fails
  while (!complete && (low <= high)) {
    // Guess number
    mid = Math.floor((low + high) / 2);
    complete = guessNumber(mid);
    if(complete){
      // Guess is correct, exit while loop
      break;
    }
    // Guess is incorrect adjust binary search parameters as needed
    if (askIfHigher(mid)) {
      low = mid + 1;
    } else {
      high = mid - 1;
    }
  }
  if(!complete){
    // Binary search terminated without getting a result
    alert('You must have picked a number outisde of 0-100');
  }else{
    alert('Congratulations! your number was: '+mid);
  }

}

startGame();
```

Comment: It is not working correctly. If I think of let's say 60, then the next guess should be 75 (according to binary search) but your code guesses 76 instead and accumulates this error over futher guesses.

Comment: That is happening due to the use of `Math.round` I tried guessing 60 and answered accordingly and got to the answer..

Comment: You get to the right answer. But "It has been suggested to use a binary search". Your binary search is broken.

Comment: Broken, how? Can you share a case where this fails?

Comment: From my limited understanding, it does not matter whether you round up or down as long as it is done consistently. Edited my answer to round down as most languages do integer truncation like that.

Comment: To Hammadi Agharass,  I agree that this is not very convenient, but this was what I was limited to and was the reason why I was stuck. Thank you to both Mr Agharass and Chirag Ravindra for the assistance.